# Yellow warning triangle in LibGDX new project

Tags: java, php, python, ruby, libgdx

I just created myself a brand new project using *LibGDX*. Usually, I don't care about how all projects have a yellow warning triangle on them, but at this point, It’s getting slightly annoying.

How can I resolve this issue?

This is what it looks like:

[image: image here]

Comment: can somEONE pls give me points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Eclipse automatically defaults to *JRE 6*. In order for you not to get those nasty warning triangles, you will need to use the *JRE 8*. The following is how you might resolve it:

### Preliminary fix

Right click one of your prjects > Build path > Configure build path

[image]

Make sure you are inside the *Libraries* submenu, from there:

Press *JRE 6* > Choose remove

Now we will add *JRE 8*:

Add Library > JRE System Library > Workspace default JRE (jre...)

[image]

### Permanentally fix

In case you want to permanentally use *JRE 8* for every LIBGDX project instead of the default *JRE 6*. You can:

Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Configure Project Specific Settings > Project > Deselect "Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.6'" > Set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.8.

That's about it.